# C# Properties.Settings

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble understanding the structure of the `Properties.Settings` syntax. I understand that this is equivalent to using the fully qualified name `MyProject.Properties.Settings` and that `Settings` is a class. But what is `Properties`? Another namespace? What's the relationship between namespace `MyProject` and namespace `MyProject.Properties`?

By the way, I've researched this exhaustively and have gotten very familiar with all the components of `Properties.Settings`. I've read dozens of articles but I haven't run across an answer to this basic question.

Comment: Properties is also a class. What's the scope of the question?

Comment: Thanks for your note. I want to understand the structure of MyProject.Properties.Settings. Is Properties used as a class here or as a namespace? I'd like to break it down so I can learn each piece.

Comment: @andypopa What do you mean its a class? Not that I can see within the Framework...

Answer (score 6):

First, to answer your question about what a namespace is... from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx):

> The namespace keyword is used to declare a scope that contains a set of related objects. You can use a namespace to organize code elements and to create globally unique types.

From another helpful page on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d941h9d.aspx):

> ... the .NET Framework uses namespaces to organize its many classes, as follows:
>
> `System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");`
>
> System is a namespace and Console is a class in that namespace.

While namespaces may serve several purposes, in a nutshell, declaring namespaces gives you a way to organize your classes. There not really a "thing" in and of themselves.

If, using the above example, the `Console` class was the *only* thing in the `System` namespace, and you deleted the `Console` class from your project (assuming you created the class), then the `System` namespace ceases to exist as it has no meaning anymore.

---

`Settings` is a class, located in the `MyProject.Properties` namespace. I have to assume that's just the namespace name they chose to give it - there doesn't seem to be any other classes in that namespace, and the classes it extends reside in the `System.Configuration` namespace.

The `Settings` class looks like this. Basically, it just creates a new instance of itself the first time you access it using the static `Settings.Default`.

```
namespace SampleWinforms.Properties
{
    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "11.0.0.0")]

    internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase 
    {
        private static Settings defaultInstance =
            ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));
        
        public static Settings Default
        {
            get { return defaultInstance; }
        }
    }
}
```

But there's nothing in there that's non-static, so what are you creating an instance of? It extends `ApplicationSettingsBase` so you're getting an instance of the contents of that class too.

There's quite a bit in there, but one of the things is an indexer that allows you to store and retrieve values (assuming the key already exists; I don't see a way to add a new setting at runtime, but if a setting was defined at compile time then you could read the value and overwrite the value at runtime).

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the value of the specified application settings property.
/// </summary>
/// 
/// <returns>
/// If found, the value of the named settings property; otherwise, null.
/// </returns>
/// <param name="propertyName">A <see cref="T:System.String"/> containing the name of the property to access.</param><exception cref="T:System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyNotFoundException">There are no properties associated with the current wrapper or the specified property could not be found.</exception><exception cref="T:System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyIsReadOnlyException">An attempt was made to set a read-only property.</exception><exception cref="T:System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyWrongTypeException">The value supplied is of a type incompatible with the settings property, during a set operation.</exception><exception cref="T:System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException">The configuration file could not be parsed.</exception><filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
public override object this[string propertyName]
{
  get
  {
    if (!this.IsSynchronized)
      return this.GetPropertyValue(propertyName);
    lock (this)
      return this.GetPropertyValue(propertyName);
  }
  set
  {
    SettingChangingEventArgs e = new SettingChangingEventArgs(propertyName, this.GetType().FullName, this.SettingsKey, value, false);
    this.OnSettingChanging((object) this, e);
    if (e.Cancel)
      return;
    base[propertyName] = value;
    this.OnPropertyChanged((object) this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

This class in turn extends `SettingsBase`, which is where the properties are stored in a `SettingsPropertyValueCollection` called "PropertyValues".

I couldn't drill down too much further, but `SettingsPropertyValueCollection` contains, among other things, a `Hashtable` and an `ArrayList` (for storing your keys and their associated values).

It also has an indexer for retrieving values, which basically just looks up the value you request.

```
 public SettingsPropertyValue this[string name]
 { 
     get
     {
         object pos = _Indices[name];

         if (pos == null || !(pos is int))
             return null; 

         int ipos = (int)pos;

         if (ipos >= _Values.Count)
             return null;

         return (SettingsPropertyValue)_Values[ipos];
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank for this, Grant. Quite helpful.

Comment: Hi Grant: Here's what I'm getting at: In the Solution Explorer, on the Properties design page, the "Assembly name" and the "Default namespace" are both MyProject. (BTW, I'm targeting 4.5 and this is a Windows App). On the Settings designer, the MyProject.Properties namespace is referenced. This difference suggests that they are two different things. If so, what's the difference?

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking `MyProject.Properties` is an automagically generated namespace. The default name of the class inside is `MyProject.Properties.Settings`, which inherits `System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase`. You can easily find all of this out by checking the `Show All Files` button at the top of your solution explorer, and then openning the generated file in MyProject->Properties->Settings.settings->Settings.Designer.cs. There is nothing special about this namespace and class, except its that VS auto generates them.

You could just as easily write your own class in another namespace which does the same thing. But that would defeat the point of having VS auto generate it for you. :)

Just a bit of an aside. The `System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase` class does add a few valuable things for you for free, such as implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: I love the phrase "automagically". Fantastic. So is the MyProject namespace separate from the MyProject.Properties namespace? If we look at MyProject as an assembly, then it can have more than one namespace. I'm sorry to slice this so thinly. I just have a hard time going deeper into this without understanding something as fundamental as what namespaces are being created and how they relate.

Comment: @TimBostwick Perhaps you would like to start a new question re: namespaces in c#/.net

Comment: You mean restart as the question, "Is the MyProject namespace separate from the MyProject.Properties namespace? And if so, are they both contained in the MyProject assembly?"

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand the concept of `namespace` at all. I must reiterate. There is nothing special about the `MyProject.Properties` namespace. It is a namespace like any other. But given that you asked "If we look at MyProject as an assembly, then it can have more than one namespace", it is clear you have no idea what a namespace is.

Comment: In the Solution Explorer, on the Properties design page, the "Assembly name" and the "Default namespace" are both MyProject. (BTW, I'm targeting 4.5 and this is a Windows App). On the Settings designer, the MyProject.Properties namespace is referenced. This difference suggests that they are two different things. If so, what's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your question correctly,

**MyProject.Properties** is like a container for your project to manage all your static references (language files/images/data connection etc...) that independent need to your project. it is like pre-defined namespace for each of your project so that you can easily know where you looking for your static resources.

Comment: @Aron: I love the phrase "automagically". Fantastic. So is the MyProject namespace separate from the MyProject.Properties namespace? If we look at MyProject as an assembly, then it can have more than one namespace. I'm sorry to slice this so thinly. I just have a hard time going deeper into this without understanding something as fundamental as what namespaces are being created and how they relate.

Comment: Reposted, thank you! Not sure what you mean by "container". I actually see it that way myself but I'm trying to nail down whether MyProject.Properties actually a namespace and if that namespace is exists separate and additionally to the MyProject namespace.